# Read content from ElementCollection annotated attribute into value object attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Exception when trying to read the content of an JPA @ElementCollection into a value object.

**The criteria code (I do not use a pre generated metamodel):**

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<KursplanListDTO> cq = cb.createQuery(KursplanListDTO.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Kursplan> Kursplan_ = m.entity(Kursplan.class);
EntityType<Institution> Institution_ = m.entity(Institution.class);
Root<Kursplan> kursplan = cq.from(Kursplan.class);
cq.multiselect(kursplan.get("id"), kursplan.get("name"), kursplan.get("institution"), kursplan.get("participants"));
TypedQuery<KursplanListDTO> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
List<KursplanListDTO> result = tq.getResultList();
```

**Entity ('Kursplan'):**

```
...
@NotNull
private String name;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Institution institution

@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name = "participants")
private List<String> participants = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

**DTO (KursplanListDTO):**

```
...
public KursplanListDTO(Long id, String name, Institution institution, List<String> participants) {
...
}
...
```

**When I run the above I get the exception:**
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [se.testapp.business.kursplan.entity.KursplanListDTO]. Expected arguments are: long, java.lang.String, se.testapp.business.systemdata.entity.Institution, java.util.Collection

**If I change List to java.util.Collection in the DTO constructor I get this exception instead (from the log):**

```
12:07:22,056 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: 
12:07:22,056 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     /* select
12:07:22,057 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         new se.testapp.business.kursplan.entity.KursplanListDTO(generatedAlias0.id,
12:07:22,057 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         generatedAlias0.name,
12:07:22,057 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         generatedAlias0.institution,
12:07:22,057 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         generatedAlias0.participants) 
12:07:22,057 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     from
12:07:22,057 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         Kursplan as generatedAlias0  */ select
12:07:22,058 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)             kursplan0_.id as col_0_0_,
12:07:22,058 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)             kursplan0_.name as col_1_0_,
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)             kursplan0_.institution_id as col_2_0_,
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)             . as col_3_0_ 
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         from
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)             Kursplan kursplan0_ 
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         inner join
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)             Institution institutio1_ 
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)                 on kursplan0_.institution_id=institutio1_.id 
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         inner join
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)             Kursplan_participants participants2_ 
12:07:22,061 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)                 on kursplan0_.id=participants2_.Kursplan_id 
12:07:22,064 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001
12:07:22,065 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Obviously the '.' on col_3_0_ does not look right.

If I leave out the 'participants', both from the multiselect and the DTO constructor it works (the other data is read into the DTO as it should).

So what can I do to make criteria let me put the content of an elementcollection into a value object (in my case the KursplanListDTO)

Java 8
JPA version: 2.1
JPA implementation: Hibernate 5

Comment: The result of a query is always a table. So it's not possible to get a Collection in the constructor

Comment: Does this mean that the only way to put an elementcollection (or any Collection) in a DTO is to (in my case) iterate through the result list and for each item/row 'sub'-query for participants-list and then update the DTO (through a setter) with the participant-list? No jpa/hbernate magic to the rescue?

Comment: Exactly. Have a look at my blog post https://martinelli.ch/2009/06/02/jpa-constructor-expression-quiz/

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The result of a query is always a table. So it's not possible to get a Collection in the constructor.

The spec defines identification variables such that they represent instances, not collections.

Read more here : https://martinelli.ch/2009/06/02/jpa-constructor-expression-quiz/